# Can I convert a WTB LaserDisc Lite hub to 15mm thru axle?

Tags: wheels, hub, replacement, front, through-axle

I have a pair of wheels that are WTB LaserDisc Lite quick release hubs laced into Mavic 717 rims.

I would like to convert the front hub from QR to 15mm thru-axle. [WTB sell replacement hub parts on their website](https://www.wtb.com/products/replacement-hub-parts?variant=32839221149773), but I'm not sure if any of them would be compatible. Is it possible? If so, are there any instructions for doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a little research and it appears there were never conversion endcaps available for that hub, and it's probably impossible due to the design.

[image]

The bearing ID itself is 15mm and it sits flush or nearly so with the edge of the shell. Therefore a conventional endcap that sits inside the bearing wouldn't be able to leave room for the axle. One can imagine a conversion endcap/seal design where the axle rides directly on the bearings and there's a free-floating element that doesn't attach to the hub, which is interesting but not very practical.

Answer (score 2):

Developing on Nathan's findings:

It *might* be possible but would require replacing those bearings, if one can be found with smaller balls and therefore a larger inner diameter hole.

Your existing 15x26x7 is a common size bearing, where 15mm is the internal diameter, 26mm is the outside diameter, and the cartridge is 7mm thick.

If you were to use 16 or 17x26x7 then you'd have 1 or 2mm to work with, resulting in a locating flange of 0.5 or 1mm in thickness.  That's not a lot.

---

Upshot - it might be possible but you're in the realms of custom machining.  Last time I got something small like that made it cost me $hundreds and that was a decade ago.  If you know someone with machining skills and equipment, then it might be possible but there are always inherent risks when prototyping bike gear.

You may be better off selling these wheels and buying a new pair that suits your needs now.